# Write a function to extract information from a dic when some key or sub keys are missing

Tags: python, if-statement, nlp

I am trying to read some information like this and want to extract the information of the key "DATE"

```py
{'DATE': {'YEAR': '1595', 'MONTH': 'October', 'DAY': '27'},
 'TIME': {'HR': '12', 'MIN': '20'},
 'AST': 'latitude',
 'ARC': '0° 0’ 25'}
```

I want to write a function in python, when key "DATE" or its sub key like 'YEAR', MONTH' ,'DAY' are missing, Raise a message saying:

"the information in the text is not enough"

When all other key is  give the result like this:

```py
('1595', 'October', 27)
```

I wrote that and it works for cases with informational but when I have case like:

```py
{'DATE': {'YEAR': '1583', 'MONTH': 'April'}, 'TIME': {}, 'ARC': '1° 50’', 'ZOD': 'Taurus', 'AST': 'latitude'
```

Which one subkey is missing raise a error

```py
def converskyfieled(sample):
    for key in sample:
        if "DATE" in key:
            if (sample[key]['YEAR']!= None) & (sample[key]['MONTH']!=None ) & (sample[key]['DAY']!= None):
                a,b,c= sample[key]['YEAR'] ,sample[key]['MONTH'], sample[key]['DAY']
                return((a),b,int(c))
            else: 
                print("not enough inofrmation form the text")
```

It should not be hard but still working on that, the above function is ok but it sucks when we have a case that some key is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it now :)

```
def converskyfieled(sample):
    if "DATE" not in sample.keys():
        print("no information in the text")
    else:
        try:
            a,b,c= sample["DATE"]['YEAR'] ,sample["DATE"]['MONTH'], sample["DATE"]['DAY']
            return((a),b,int(c))
        except KeyError:
            print("incomplete information in the text")
```